# duplicateMovieClip is deleting my clip?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm trying to duplicate a movieClip that I created using attachMovie (it also has a number of smaller clips in it that I also put there using attachMovie). I can't seem to "find" the clip's name, and when I do, or when I think I do, like this:

```
_level0.products.box0.duplicateMovieClip('newMc', 100);
```

The clip actually gets deleted! This is highly unexpected behavior. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? The movieclip exists at that address, I can set its _x and _y etc.

Comment: I don't think it is getting deleted from there. The cause of it may be the `depth` of the duplicated movieclip. Because a hard coded `100` is there to set the depth of the duplicate mc and diplay objects won't share the same depth rather each has their unique `depth`.

Comment: Even though I checked to make sure that nothing else shares a depth of 100 with that clip?

Comment: have u traced `_level0.products.box0` if so what it returned? and have u tried `_level0.products.getNextHighestDepth()` instead of `100`?